# OSX Error installing subversion via macports

Tags: macos, svn, macports

I'm attempting to install subversion 1.7.2 ( upgrading from default Lion version, 1.6? ).
Running `sudo port install subversion` the installing completes successfully however I receive this error when running "svn --version"

`$ svn --version

      dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib

      Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/svn

      Reason: Incompatible library version: svn requires version 8.0.0 or later, but    libexpat.1.dylib provides version 7.0.0

   Trace/BPT trap: 5`

How can I upgrade the libexpat library to make appease SVN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current MacPorts version of libexpat should be version 8.  Make sure you don't have another version of `libexpat` installed in `/usr/local`; that can sometimes interfere with Port builds and installs.  Then update, clean, and reinstall both the `expat` and `subversion` ports:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port clean expat subversion
sudo port -n upgrade --force expat subversion
```

Comment: This pretty much worked, except I did not have to be so explicite. Luckily 'port update outdated', was all it took. But your answer is precise! thx :)

Comment: Good. MacPorts port file are updated frequently by the project.  It's a good idea to always make sure you are using the most recent versions by doing `port selfupdate` first.

Comment: what is 'expat' here, and how it is possible to install it?

Comment: `expat` is a widely-used XML parser library (http://www.libexpat.org/
).  If you are using MacPorts as a package manager on OS X, `expat` is available as a MacPorts port file (https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/textproc/expat/Portfile).  It is normally specified as a dependency by other ports so it gets installed automatically when installing other ports but you can install it explicitly with `sudo port install expat`.  An older version of `libexpat` is included in OS X.  And you can always install it from source yourself.