# uWSGI issue: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libexpat.1.dylib

Tags: macos, uwsgi

Trying to run uwsgi in Sierra 10.12.6, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libexpat.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  Reason: Incompatible library version: uwsgi requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libexpat.1.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried:

```
brew update
brew reinstall expat
```

and reinstalling uwsgi with pip, but no luck. Any idea what the fix would be?

Comment: Could you include the output of `otool -l /usr/local/bin/uwsgi`? Specifically the part about `LC_RPATH`.

Comment: Did you eve solve this problem?

Comment: Never solved this problem.
Also, there is no LC_RPATH portion when I run `otool -l /usr/local/bin/uwsgi`

Comment: Do these answers help you at all? https://superuser.com/questions/736210/how-do-i-remove-an-old-version-of-iconv-on-which-other-software-depends-and-ot/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066370/osx-error-installing-subversion-via-macports

Answer (score 1):

Inside your activated virtual environment, force `UWSGI` reinstall and force a rebuild of all the `UWSGI` deps + ignoring the cache. Run:

```
pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: This did the trick for me! I had installed `supervisor` via `brew` and it updated my system `python` from `3.7` to `3.8`. This caused some problems with libs that only supported `3.7`. Then, I decided to use `pyenv`, installed python `3.7.8` and created a new `venv` from scratch, everything was working fine but the `uwsgi`, that for some reason was trying to use `/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python` (that no longer existed because `brew` removed it) instead of my `venv` `python`! Your command solved everything, after 50+ tabs of browsing, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

you can install from conda. To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi

conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 uwsgi 

conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken uwsgi 

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 uwsgi
```

its work for me!